# To display selected value from autocomplete on the table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am using `autocomplete` and `table` component on the same `page/component`.Here on selecting particular `player` from the list of autocomplete component i want display that selected player details(for ex `NAME` and `AGE`) on the table like  this :

[image]

I got some examples **to display the selected value on the input field**. Unable find it for table component.

Stackblitz [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bfbk4z-uzle2g?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.ts)

Comment: Give my answer a try to check if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your current implementation:

1. You'll have to work with `ELEMENT_DATA` to filter the results out instead of the `options`.
2. You will have to reassign to `dataSource` the fileted array of results. That's something that I've done in the `_filter` method. But since it returned `string[]` and I was filtering on `ELEMENT_DATA` I changed its return type to `PeriodicElement[]`.
3. Also, you're using `options` for the AutoComplete Suggestions instead of which you can simply use `filteredOptions` and then use `option.name` in the `mat-option` with the string interpolation syntax(`{{}}`)

Give this a try:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {MatSort,MatPaginator,  MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { name: 'Sachin Tendulkar', age: 42, },
  { name: 'Virat Kohli', age: 30},
];

@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-filter-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-filter-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-filter-example.css'],
})
export class AutocompleteFilterExample implements OnInit {
    displayedColumns: string[] = [ 'name', 'age'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: string[] = ['Sachin Tendulkar', 'Virat Kohli', 'Rohith Sharma'];
  filteredOptions: Observable<PeriodicElement[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

 applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  private _filter(value: string): PeriodicElement[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    const filteredSet = ELEMENT_DATA.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(filteredSet);
    return filteredSet;
  }
}


/**  Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

And in your template:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick Player" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">

      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>


<!-- <mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field> -->


<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">


  <!-- NAME Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> NAME </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

   <!-- AGE Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> AGE </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.age}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

---

Here's an [**Updated and Working StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-filter-and-sort-eg?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.html) for your ref.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I just hardcoded the data in table, actually the data as to be in the `autocomplete` component. If  select from autocomplete list(for ex Sachin). I want display sachin's details on the table.

Comment: Isn't that what's happening on the Updated stackBlitz?

Comment: In yours `stackblitz example` the hard coded data is still present,

Comment: By default the table will be empty.Only on selecting from the list(i,e autocomplete) the table row will be added.

Answer (score 0):

Bind `keydown` event on input field as  `(keydown)="handlekeypressEvent($event.target.value)"`, 
 
Change the table data according to keydownevent value.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Pick Player" 
(keydown)="handlekeypressEvent($event.target.value)" aria-label="Number"
 matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">

handlekeypressEvent($event) {
      console.log($event);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA.filter(e=> 
                         e.name.toLowerCase().includes($event.toLowerCase())));
    }
```

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-according-to-autocomplete?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Will this work?

[Updated And Reworked!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bfbk4z-dtohaz?embed=1&file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.ts)

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
```

This will make sure your table is empty initially.

Add this in ngOnInit function

```
this.myControl.valueChanges
  .subscribe(v => {

    if (!v) {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
      return;
    }

    const newDataSource = ELEMENT_DATA.filter(ob => ob.name === v);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(newDataSource);
  });
```

And when you change the value from dropdown, this will populate the table.

P.S.:

Let me know, if I am still not getting your goal.

Comment: Please see my question once..:)